# Furnace Pilot Flame ON constant but Main Burner never kicks in

Tags: furnace

I own an older furnace (Armstrong EG6F80DC12-6 -- natural gas, forced air, single stage, Honeywell S8600C Continuous Re-Try Module, VR8204A Gas Valve w/ Pilot Burner / Igniter-Sensor).  It has been old faithful but since Saturday i've been experiencing issues with it heating.

When the thermostat calls for heat the following occurs at the furnace:

1. Inducer Blower Motor starts spinning
2. Gas valve opens
3. The pilot is lit -- i can see a wide blue flame.  The flame remains on.

The furnace remains at #3, constantly on, for as long as the thermostat is calling for heat.  I hear no clicks after the pilot light is on nor does the flame or system shut down.  The home, of course, is slowly getting colder since the main burner never kicks in.

What troubleshooting steps should i perform?  I've never dealt with such a problem before.  Working inside the furnace is new to me but willing to learn.